# Why can Chrome get file, but not Safari?

Tags: node.js, http, web, safari, xmlhttprequest

**[The URL](http://121.43.197.11/?c=94&i=3346&n=%E6%88%91%E7%9A%84%E8%90%8C%E9%9D%A2&f=1,1,1,1,1,1&k=1001)**

Open this url in Chrome is all fine, but when open it in Safari, some files can't get forever.

**OK in Chrome:**
[image: OK in Chrome]

**BAD in Safari:**
[image: BAD in Safari]

As you can see, all plist file and ExportJson file can't get in Safari. But they all exists in server.

Like `faceshow_10.plist`, it's url is http://121.43.197.11/res/faceShow/faceshow_10.plist.

And in Chrome is all ok.

## Question:

Why this happen? And How should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the plist resources under the same domain. You may need to check the cross domain problem [XHR](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Articles/XHR.html) .